# Error while Launching the application. Error while executing command 'c:\(...)node_modules\.bin\react-native.cmd run-android --no-packager'

Tags: android, android-studio, visual-studio-code

This is the problem I'm getting while trying to launch an android app (android studio) on visual studio code.

I dont know if it is a connection problem between VS Code and Android Studio.

> An error occurred while launching the application. Error while executing command 'c:\Users\dmdpl\OneDrive\Desktop\citas3\node_modules.bin\react-native.cmd run-android --no-packager' (error code 101) (error code 303)

This is what the code where the problem is says:

```
 "version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Debug Android",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "type": "reactnative",
        "request": "launch",
        "platform": "android",
        "isDynamic": true
    },
    {
        "name": "Run Android",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "type": "reactnative",
        "request": "launch",
        "platform": "android",
        "enableDebug": false,
        "isDynamic": true
    }
]
```